# How would you write an less computationally intensive equivalent of numpy.where(np.ones(shape))

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to get a list of elements for an array of a given shape.
I found one easy way to do that:

```
import numpy as np
shape = (3,3)
elements = np.where(np.ones(shape))
```

the result is

```
>>> elements
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

This is the expected behaviour. However it doesn't seem to be the most compute-efficient way. f shape is huge, then np.where can be quite sluggish. I am looking for a more compute-efficient solution. Any idea?

Comment: `numpy.mgrid` along with `.flatten()` might suit your needs

Comment: at what shape are you seeing performance degrade?

Comment: `(np.repeat(np.arange(shape[0]), shape[1]), np.tile(np.arange(shape[1]), shape[0]))` seems to be about 2-3 times faster, so still kinda slow (at a shape of 1e5 x 1e4).

Comment: There are lots of ways of generating all indicies, depending on the format that you need -l they've all been discussed in related questions.  But why do you need such a tuple or list (or array)?  If generating them is computationally expensive, won't using them be also?

Comment: thanks guys for your comments. I have tested the three solutions and they are comparable. I would have thought that numpy.where would be computationally intense but it turns out not to be the case with this simple test np.where(np.ones(shape))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I have received, I implemented 3 ways to get the same result and tested their performance.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def with_where(a):
    shape = a.shape
    return np.where(np.ones(shape))
def with_mgrid(a):
    shape = a.shape
    grid_shape = (len(shape), np.prod(shape))
    return np.mgrid[0:shape[0],0:shape[1]].reshape(grid_shape)
def with_repeat(a):
    shape = a.shape
    np.repeat(np.arange(shape[0]), shape[1]), np.tile(np.arange(shape[1]), shape[0])

a1 = np.ones((1,1))
a10 = np.ones((10,10))
a100 = np.ones((100,100))
a1000 = np.ones((1000,1000))
a10000 = np.ones((10000,10000))
```

Then I ran %timeit in ipython

```
%timeit with_where(a1)
%timeit with_where(a10)
%timeit with_where(a100)
%timeit with_where(a1000)
%timeit with_where(a10000)

11.1 µs ± 163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
12.7 µs ± 39.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
146 µs ± 1.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
16.2 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.49 s ± 58.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit with_mgrid(a1)
%timeit with_mgrid(a10)
%timeit with_mgrid(a100)
%timeit with_mgrid(a1000)
%timeit with_mgrid(a10000)

50.2 µs ± 2.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
45.9 µs ± 989 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
75.1 µs ± 1.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
6.17 ms ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.1 s ± 40.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit with_repeat(a1)
%timeit with_repeat(a10)
%timeit with_repeat(a100)
%timeit with_repeat(a1000)
%timeit with_repeat(a10000)

23.3 µs ± 931 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
31 µs ± 739 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
66 µs ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
4.41 ms ± 127 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.05 s ± 22.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

so for large arrays, the method with np.where is about 2x as slow as the fastest method. This is not as bad as I thought.